# htacces rewrite rule conflict with other url

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have the Following htaccess file. the problem is while goto page2.php its going to page1.php like this page3.php goes to page1.php.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /bookshow/


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /page1\.php\?name=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /page2\.php\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=302,NE,L]


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /page3\.php\?cat=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=302,NE,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ page1.php?name=$1 [L,NE,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ page2.php?id=$1 [L,NE,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ page3.php?cat=$1 [L,NE,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: What you want to do. Its ok where it is going but where should it must go ??

Comment: page1.php  and page3.php Works Fine. BUT WHILE GOTO PAGE2.PHP IT LANDS ON PAGE1.PHP this is the problem. page2.php must goto page2.php

Comment: What Will Be the Solution?

Comment: You have the same condition for all of your rewriterules. How is the server going to know what page your asking for when you have all 3 rules checking for any URI request? RewriteRule **^([^/]*)/?$**

Comment: @PanamaJack   So... What Will Be The Solution?

Comment: @PanamaJack How i have to change the RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ ... i Dont have idea on this

Answer (score 2):

As Panama Jack stated, the server cannot simply *guess* which rewrite needs to occur after the page has been redirected, simply because the patterns for each of your three rules are *exactly the same*. As such, the first rule will *always* execute, and nothing else will.

To tackle this, use the following code instead:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /bookshow/

# Step 1: Redirect all pagex.php?... to new URIs

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} cat=([^\s&]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^page1.php$ cat/%1? [R=302,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} name=([^\s&]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^page2.php$ name/%1? [R=302,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=([^\s&]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^page3.php$ id/%1? [R=302,NE,L]

# Step 2: Rewrite cat/something, name/something, id/something to the actual pages

RewriteRule ^cat/([^/]*)/?$ page1.php?cat=$1&r [L,NE,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^name/([^/]*)/?$ page2.php?name=$1&r [L,NE,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^id/([^/]*)/?$ page3.php?id=$1&r [L,NE,QSA,NC]
```

**Further Explanation:**

In the *first step*, we're checking which page is being access with what query string. If there is a match, redirect to the new URI.

For example, **page1.php?cat=hello** will redirect to **cat/hello**.

Then, in the second step, we rewrite these new URIs to the already-existing pages, and append `&r` to the query string so we avoid a redirect loop. This `&r` is basically redundant, and acts like a dummy.

For example, **cat/hello** will internally rewrite to **page1.php?cat=hello&r**.

**Updated:** I have removed `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` from the code as well - these are not needed. Feel free to put them back if you ever land up needing them.