# htaccess url rewrite goes to first link

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My htaccess file have rewrite rule for three urls. but all three urls goes to the first url only. following is the htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /tamiloosai/


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /page1\.php\?cat=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=302,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /page2\.php\?name=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=302,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /page3\.php\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=302,NE,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ page1.php?cat=$1 [L,NE,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ page2.php?name=$1 [L,NE,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ page3.php?id=$1 [L,NE,QSA,NC]
```

while goto page1.php it goes to page1.php  and same as page2.php and page3.php also goes to page1.php, but page2.php must goto page2.php and page3.php must goto page3.php  how to solve this issue?

Comment: @Starkeen no man....

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30077865/htacces-rewrite-rule-conflict-with-other-url

Comment: Please see my answer **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30103018/1626250)**

Comment: Don't double-post. If you want to improve a question, click edit under it and improve it.